# Custom gson deserializer for Date never gets called

Tags: java, date, serialization, gson, retrofit

As far as I can tell, gson does not automatically serialize and deserialize java.util.Date objects into ISO strings like "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ" or for example "2014-04-15T18:22:00-05:00". So in order for me to communicate dates properly between my client (using Retrofit with gson) and server, I need to specify the DateFormat to gson. Here is what I've done:

```
// code defining the creation of a RestAdapter
// ...
new GsonBuilder()
    .setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ")
    .create()
```

Adding the .setDateFormat line was enough to get gson to properly deserialize timestamp strings into Date objects. However, it did not serialize Date objects into timestamp strings. So I assumed that I would have to create a custom serializer like so:

```
// code defining the creation of a RestAdapter
// ...
new GsonBuilder()
    .setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ")
    .registerTypeAdapter(Date.class, new DateSerializer())
    .create()
```

and the DateSerializer class:

```
class DateSerializer implements JsonSerializer<Date> {
    @Override
    public JsonElement serialize(Date arg0, Type arg1, JsonSerializationContext arg2) {
        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ", Locale.US);
        return new JsonPrimitive(df.format(arg0));
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, the serialize function is ignored. Instead gson formats the date as a string like "Tues Mar 15 18:22:00 EST 2014". So to test, I tried replacing the serialize function with:

```
public JsonElement serialize(Date arg0, Type arg1, JsonSerializationContext arg2) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Serialize function called!");
}
```

But of course that RuntimeException is never thrown.

Does anyone know why my serialize function is ignored? I think I read somewhere that for some types a registerTypeAdapter will be ignored if there is one defined for a superclass, but since this is java.util.Date I would be confused if that was the problem. I'm probably just doing something stupid, but I probably don't know Date or gson well enough to realize it.

EDIT: Provided more context around the code below:

**MyApplication.java**

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    public static RestAdapter restAdapter;
    public static The1Api the1Api;

    public static void createRestAdapter(String server_url){
        // enable cookies
        CookieManager cookieManager = new CookieManager();
        cookieManager.setCookiePolicy(CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL);
        CookieHandler.setDefault(cookieManager);

        // create rest adapter
        restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setEndpoint(server_url)
            .setConverter(new GsonConverter(new GsonBuilder()
                    .setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ")
                    .registerTypeAdapter(Date.class, new DateSerializer())
                    .create()))
            .setLogLevel(LogLevel.FULL)
            .setLog(new ResponseInterceptor())
            .build();

        // create API
        the1Api = restAdapter.create(The1Api.class);
    }
}
```

**The1Api.java**

```
public interface The1Api {
    /* Chat */

    public class PublicMessage {
        String from_user;
        String message;
        Date time;
        Integer microsecond;
        Boolean in_1_percent;
    }
    public class PublicMessageList {
        Integer last_message_id;
        ArrayList<PublicMessage> messages;
    }

    @GET("/chat/get_public_messages/")
    public PublicMessageList getPublicMessages(
            @Query("last_message_id") Integer last_message_id, // optional
            @Query("since") Date since, // optional
            @Query("max") Integer max // optional
            );   

    // ...
}
```

**LoginActivity.java**

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity {
    // ...

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Crashlytics.start(this);
        MyApplication.createRestAdapter(getString(R.string.server_url));
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Thread thread = new Thread(){
            @Override
            public void run(){
                ArrayList<The1Api.PublicMessage> publicMessages = MyApplication.the1Api.getPublicMessages(null, null, null).messages;
                for (The1Api.PublicMessage m : publicMessages){
                    Log.d("The1", "[" + m.time.toString() + "] " + m.from_user + ": " + m.message);
                }
                // when the following line gets executed, my server receives a request including the date below,
                // but the server does not understand the format of the date because it does not get serialized properly
                MyApplication.the1Api.getPublicMessages(null, new Date(1000000000), null);
            }
        };
        thread.start();
    }

    // ...    
}
```

**DateSerializer.java**

```
class DateSerializer implements JsonSerializer<Date> {
    @Override
    public JsonElement serialize(Date arg0, Type arg1, JsonSerializationContext arg2) {
        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ", Locale.US);
        return new JsonPrimitive(df.format(arg0));
    }
}
```

EDIT 2: No solutions as of yet, but as a workaround you can manually convert the Date to some other format before sending it. In the comments Kalel suggested converting it to a String, I converted it to a Long (number of seconds since UNIX epoch).

Comment: First look at `SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ", Locale.US);` and `df.format(arg0)`. If it works perfectly then go to next step to define your custom Serializer. For more info look at [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: When I tried to debug those lines earlier, I noticed that they were never called- hence why I tried replacing the code with throwing a RuntimeException instead. However, since the serializer never gets called that can't be the problem even if those lines are wrong, could it?

Comment: So the problem is that serializer never gets called. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Can you post your complete code. What JSON are you using? How returned Gson is used?

Comment: Correct, my problem is that the serializer never gets called, or so it seems. I have provided more context, hopefully not omitting anything that would be important. I am using Retrofit 1.5.0 with gson 2.2.4.

Comment: Can you try simply `new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(Date.class, new DateSerializer()).create();` without `setDateFormat()`. Sorry I don't have any idea about Activity but it will be helpful for others to solve it.

Comment: Commenting out setDateFormat unfortunately doesn't change anything (except that Date objects are not deserialized properly anymore, of course). I added a few extra lines to LoginActivity.java to show an example of how the server call works when no date is passed (and the Log outputs the correct information so the timestamp is normally being properly deserialized to a Date object).

Comment: if your date object is null then DateSerializer will not be called, or formatters cannot produce timestamps,but your serializer should wrok

Comment: I realize that in LoginActivity.java the first call to getPublicMessages won't call the serializer since the second parameter is null, but shouldn't the serializer get called the second time getPublicMessages is called where the second parameter is new Date(1000000000)?

Comment: I can verify this issue. It doesn't seem that Path or Query dates get serialized at all. For a temp solution, convert them to string before sending them to the server and then let the server reparse them to the correct format. Not Ideal by any means, but works until a solution is found for this.

Comment: Thanks Kalel, that should work! After talking with one of the other engineers on this project we just decided to pass around datetimes as longs (number of seconds since UNIX epoch) and that seems to be working for us. Since it's just a workaround though I'll leave the question open in case Retrofit/Gson gets updated (I'm not sure who's to blame).

Answer (score 1):

Are you still able to replicate this issue?  I'm seeing Gson serialize and deserialize correctly.  It's possible this is a Retrofit issue (I've not used it before), but looking at the docs for [`GsonConverter`](http://square.github.io/retrofit/javadoc/retrofit/converter/GsonConverter.html) I see no reason it would do anything other than delegate to the provided in `Gson` object.

Here's an SSCCE:

```
public class GsonDateDemo {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        .setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ")
        .registerTypeAdapter(Date.class, new DateSerializer())
        .create();
    Date d = new Date(1438806977000L);

    System.out.println("Serializing "+d);
    String json = gson.toJson(d);
    System.out.println("JSON: "+json);
    Date d2 = gson.fromJson(json, Date.class);
    System.out.println("Deserialized: "+d2);
    System.out.println("Equal? "+d.equals(d2));
  }

  static class DateSerializer implements JsonSerializer<Date> {
    @Override
    public JsonElement serialize(Date arg0, Type arg1, JsonSerializationContext arg2) {
      System.out.println("Serializer received "+arg0);
      SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ", Locale.US);
      return new JsonPrimitive(df.format(arg0));
    }
  }
}
```

This outputs:

```
Calling: local.GsonDateDemo.main[]
Serializing Wed Aug 05 16:36:17 EDT 2015
Serializer received Wed Aug 05 16:36:17 EDT 2015
JSON: "2015-08-05T16:36:17-0400"
Deserialized: Wed Aug 05 16:36:17 EDT 2015
Equal? true
```

If you can, modify this SSCCE to use Retrofit and see if you can replicate the failure that way.

Comment: I haven't worked on this project for some time now; I'm afraid I won't be able to give this a try. If I run into a similar problem again, I'll come back to this.
Maybe someone else that's experienced the issue will be able to share their thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

The problem in gson, when we try to deserialize with after call `setDateFormat`, custom `DateDesializer` not calling.

So when you are deserializing don't call `setDateFormat` ;)